# Trying to get rid of an error

Tags: errors

I've got this code

```
\[\framebox[1.1\width]{$\mathbb{P}$ (future $\vert$ past and present) =
  $\mathbb{P}$ (future $\vert$ present)} \par\]
```

Which shows what I want it to but I get the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `$`inside `\[` it's unnecessary as `\[` already starts math mode. Likewise `\par` shouldn't be inside a math environment.

Comment: Separately, don't use `\par` -- a text-mode command par excellence -- inside a displayed equation environment.

Comment: @DaiBowen -- while your statement about not using `$` inside `\[ ... \]` is generally true, in this case the expression is boxed, so it has been turned into text mode, where the `$` are necessary.

Comment: @barbarabeeton indeed, so I learnt to my surprise from the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\par` inside a math display. Remove it and things will work as expected. Here's a slight alternative to your setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\mathbb{P}(#1)}
\newcommand{\given}{\vert}

\begin{document}

\[
  \framebox[1.1\width]{%
    $\prob{\text{future $\given$ past and present}} =
    \prob{\text{future $\given$ present}}$%
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `\par`, which is not allowed (and makes no sense either) in a math display.

It's easier if you use the predefined command `\boxed`.

Note that you should treat math as math and text as text, so the bar should be outside `\text` and typed in as `\mid`.

Note that the command `\Pr` is defined to print an upright “P” as a math operator, so it's possible and even recommended to redefine it as liked.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\Pr}{\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\boxed{
  \quad
    \Pr(\text{future} \mid \text{past and present}) =
    \Pr(\text{future} \mid \text{present})
   \quad
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]